# select data from mysql views

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 2 tables **subscribed-channels** and channel-videos.
What i want to achieve is. Select maximum 5 channels from subscribed-channels and then maximum 4 videos fro each channel.
The channels’s position need to be sorted by their **most recent uploaded video time**. Example below.

- Channel 1 – last video uploaded was 5 days ago.
- Channel 2 – last video was uploaded 3 days ago.
- Channel 3 – last video was uploaded 1 hour ago.

Position in the subscribed-channels.php page for these channels will be like this:

- Position 1 (at the top) – Channel 3
- Position 2 – Channel 2
- Position 3 – Channel 1.

kindly guide me how to write this query.
**What I tried:**

```
SELECT
  usersubscriptions.*,
  uservideos.videoId,uservideos.videoThumbnail
FROM
  usersubscriptions
JOIN
  uservideos ON usersubscriptions.subscribedTo = uservideos.userId
ORDER BY
  uservideos.videoTime DESC,
  usersubscriptions.subscribedTo
```

I created the join but i am not able to limit the data or sort it.

Comment: What you have tried? please share your code.

Comment: @ravisachaniya please check the updated question. I tried by joining tables and sorting by time.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeking a "**top n per category**" (top 4 per channel) solution. This is harder than it could be because MySQL (as at v5.7 as current) lacks window functions in general and `row_number()` in particular. There is however a workaround using variables to mimic `row_number()`

```
SELECT
       *
FROM (
      SELECT
            usersubscriptions.*
          , uservideos.videoId
          , uservideos.videoTime
          , uservideos.videoThumbnail
          , @rn := IF(@prev = usersubscriptions.subscribedTo, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn
          , @prev := usersubscriptions.subscribedTo
      FROM usersubscriptions
      JOIN uservideos ON usersubscriptions.subscribedTo = uservideos.userId
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars
      ORDER BY
            usersubscriptions.subscribedTo
          , uservideos.videoTime DESC
      ) d
WHERE rn <= 4
ORDER BY
      d.videoTime DESC
    , d.subscribedTo
LIMIT 20
;
```

Comment: The order by clause is giving error videoTime and subscribedTo clumns are not recognized

Comment: Can I call this query from php. ??

Comment: can you tell me how to convert this into a view, as cuurently it gives me error because views can't have variables

Comment: `videoTime` I noticed lack of that column in your query too late for my original post, added it a while ago. You must have grabbed tit before I did that edit. Don't blame me if the other column is missing because every column from that table is available due to `usersubscriptions.*`

Comment: You will not be able to make this into a view. Why would you not be able to call this from php? Just take care that you preserve the query when you form the query string. like any other query.

Comment: I am not blaming you sir, I guess the order by clause is outside context somehow, as the query returned me results after removing the order by clause completely

Comment: yes, the aliases were incorrect, so it was my fault :) *c'est la vie*

Comment: how can i call this from php for a specific user id in usersubscription table.

Comment: **prepared statement** search for it. I have done all I can. php simply is not my thing. there are simply a billion examples if you research it you might need another question though and you would need to actually show what php you are attempting to get to work.

Comment: one last favor, can you guide me how to group the result returned by this query based on usersubscription.subscribedTo

Comment: You do not need "group by" in SQL, You are now discussing how to make it look pretty and that is done in PHP. Don't confuse these roles (too many people do) SQL is NOT a report generator.